# How to manage CalendarList for another user

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am in the process of migrating Google Calendar API from V2 - V3. I need to update another users CalendarList. This was possible in V2 by overriding the requestor_id field on the OAuth token. But now that I am also using OAuth2, this technique doesn't work.

The request for listing CalendarLists is:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList

So I presumed exchanging 'me' for the users email address would work ...

GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/someemail@domain.com/calendarList

... but it doesn't - the API returns a 404 Not Found error.

Is this functionality possible using Calendar API V3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to use [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount) authorization. Good description how to use it you can find on this page: [Perform Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation). It describes this process for `Drive API`, but you can use it for `Calendar API v3` as well. Scopes for `Calendar API` you can find on this page: [Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth). You have to understand one thing: when you want to work with different users - you have to create new `Calendar` service object for each user.

Comment: thanks for the response. i am already using a service account. i was just missing the 'sub' parameter - so thanks for the pointer my problem is now solved.